# Equality of vector-valued Radon measures

Tags: measure-theory

The notations are similar to those in *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by L. Evans and R. Gariepy. I am new to this topic.

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued Radon measures on $\Omega$, bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, such that $\forall \Psi\in C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}}\Psi \cdot d\mu=\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}}\Psi \cdot d\nu.
\end{align*}

I wish to prove that $\mu=\nu$. As $C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$ is dense in $C_c(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$, let $\Psi_n \in C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$ be such that $\Psi_n$ uniformly converges to $\Psi\in C_c(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$. Using the polar decomposition of $\mu$ as $\sigma|\mu|$ with $|\sigma|=1$, $|\mu|$-a.e., one has:
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}} \Psi_n d\mu=
\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}} \Psi_n\cdot\sigma d|\mu|\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow }\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}} \Psi\cdot\sigma d|\mu|=\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}} \Psi d\mu.
\end{align*}
Arguing similarly with $\nu$,
we deduce that $\forall \varphi\in C_c(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^2)$,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}}\varphi \cdot d\mu=\displaystyle{\int_{\Omega}}\varphi \cdot d\nu,
\end{align*}
yielding the desired result.
Am I right? I do thank you for your attention.